# Hack the standard function in library and call the native library function afterwards

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I am trying to hack the malloc function to call my malloc function first.Once my malloc function is executed within that, I want to invoke the standard malloc. But, I am getting a recursion, since it is just loading my defined malloc. How can i fix the below code?

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "stdio.h"
//#include "stdlib.h"


void *handle;

void *handle_malloc;

int (*loadprg)(void);

void * (*malloc_sysm)(size_t);


void init()
{
    handle = dlopen ("/export/home/joshis1/Foxtel/temp/libloadmap.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if( handle == NULL)
     {
       puts(dlerror());
     }


   handle_malloc = dlopen ("/lib/libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
    if( handle_malloc == NULL)
     {
       puts("handle malloc error\r\n");
       puts(dlerror());
     }


}


#include "stdio.h"


void *malloc(int size)
{
   printf("called..my malloc\r\n");

   malloc_sysm = dlsym(handle_malloc,"malloc");

   if ( dlerror() != NULL)
    {
       puts("malloc symbol not found..");
       exit(1);
    }


    printf("This should call actual malloc now..\r\n");
    return  malloc_sysm(size);




}


int main()
{
  int *t;
  init();
  printf("call load program now\r\n");

  loadprg = dlsym(handle, "loadprg");

  if( dlerror()!= NULL)
   {
      puts("Symbol load errror");
   }

  (*loadprg)();  

  printf("Close the handle now..\r\n");

  dlclose(handle);


  t = (int *) malloc (100);

  dlclose(handle_malloc);



  return 0;

}
```

The output is recursion to my defined malloc(). how to fix this?

Comment: Wow, that's a [classic](http://www.iecc.com/linker/linker09.html) hack you're trying to use.

Comment: If you're using GNU libc, you might also look at [memory allocation hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To override shared functions you need to compile your own shared library and preload it via the LD_PRELOAD environment variable.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void *malloc(size_t size) {
    printf("called..my malloc\r\n");

    void *(*original_malloc)(size_t size);
    // Find original malloc function
    original_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");

    if ( dlerror() != NULL)
    {
        puts("malloc symbol not found..");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("This should call actual malloc now..\r\n");
    return (*original_malloc)(size);
}

$ gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o mymalloc.so mymalloc.c -ldl
$ LD_PRELOAD=./mymalloc.so ./prog
```

Now your program will use malloc from preloaded library.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way I'm always using is creating a macro called `MALLOC` (or `MYMALLOC` or whatever) which does what you want.  All occurrences of `malloc` I have to replace by the use of the macro, of course, and I can understand when this is not what you want.

You also can achieve what you want by defining a macro called `malloc` (i. e. spelled like the original `malloc`) only when compiling the source you want to have your feature in.  This `malloc` macro then would call a function called, say, `wrappingMalloc` which should be declared in a file which is compiled without defining the macro `malloc` and which then in turn can call the original function `malloc`.  If this makefile fiddling is too much for you, you could also call the original function by calling `(malloc)` (this avoids running into the macro again):

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define malloc(size) myMalloc(size)

    void *myMalloc(size_t size) {
      void *result;
      printf("mallocing %ld bytes", size);
      result = (malloc)(size);
      printf(" at %p\n", result);
      return result;
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      char *buffer;
      buffer = malloc(10);
      return 0;
    }
```

In C++ you might get along by overloading the `new` operator for your classes.

Comment: I really liked your answer also.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see a problem in your code. But why not move `malloc_sysm = dlsym(handle_malloc,"malloc");` into your `init()` function?